# Bare metal USB on the Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: pi-3, usb, bare-metal

I have been trying to learn the working of USB drivers through the on-board port on the Raspberry Pi 3B(BCM2837). I'm referring to this repo for the source code: https://github.com/xinu-os/xinu/blob/master/system/platforms/arm-rpi/bcm2835_power.c
After booting the kernel, the logic gets stuck at SYSERR part. When I plug in a USB stick, does the stick LEDs light up by default or while doing some read/write operations? If I understood correctly, the bcm2835_setpower function is enabling power supply to the peripherals?

---

I referred to another repo: https://github.com/rsta2/uspi/blob/cb82923c079853bc53e70c7afd620ae9a2154150/lib/dwhcidevice.c#L433
They seem to be doing the same thing: Setting register 0x3F000000 + 0x980000 + 0xE00 to 0? There seems to be no power supply at the peripherals. Any help on the topic is appreciated.